# Electric field 0 everywhere inside Gaussian surface

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity, classical-electrodynamics

Gauss's Law shows that the electric field everywhere inside a spherical shell of uniform charge density is $0$. Suppose we have a surface which divides space into two disjoint regions (an interior and exterior). If the electric field is $0$ everywhere interior to the surface, does it follow that the surface is a spherical shell of uniform charge density?

Edit: I am stupid. As Alfred Centauri pointed out, a zero electric field everywhere means there is no restriction on the surface. So let me impose the condition that the surface does not have charge zero.

Comment: The differential form of Gauss' law is $\nabla \cdot {\vec E} = \rho / \epsilon_0$. If $\vec E = 0$ everywhere inside the spherical shell, then how do you have a charge there, i.e. $\rho \ne 0$?

Comment: Is this the question as it is asked on your homework assignment?

Comment: @JoshuaBenabou is the charge distributed only on the surface of the spherical shell?

Comment: @Sofia: I don't know vector calculus too well and in any case I am familiar only with the integral form of Gauss's Law. I don't understand your question. Is it not true that the electric field is zero everywhere inside a spherical shell of uniform charge density. According to my textbook this is this case.

Comment: @garyp: please don't presume this is a homework assignment. this is a question i formulated myself. i posed it in a concise manner so as to be clear. Apologies if the question is malformed, as I don't think I fully understand Gauss's law anyways.

Comment: A counter-example would prove the conjecture false.  Consider the case that the electric field is zero everywhere in which case *any* Gaussian surface will have zero electric field inside.

Comment: @JoshuaBenabou  aha! It's O.K. But if the surface that you take as separating between interior and exterior, can be any surface, right? As long as interior to this surface $\vec E = 0$, it means that, if there are charges, they are outside this surface, right?

Comment: @JoshuaBenabou about the spherical symmetry of the charges. What if you choose the surface to separate between interior and exterior, spherical?

Comment: @AlfredCentauri: you are right, so lets assume that the charge on the surface is not 0. Sofia: I don't understand what your saying. I am asking the question does the surface HAVE to be spherical (we already know a spherical surface satisfies the conditions).

Comment: @JoshuaBenabou I tried to say something, namely if the maximal volume inside which the field is zero at each point, has a spherical form, then the charges, if they exist, and are of the same sign and uniformly distributed, **then** they are distributed on a shell (but I don't know of which thickness). But if the maximal volume of field 0 inside is not spherical, it's sure that you cannot say that the charges outside are distributed with spherical symmetry.

Comment: @JoshuaBenabou  But let me tell you something more: assume that you have a spherical volume in which, at every point $\vec E = 0$. If there are charges outside this volume, you can consider their distribution ***equivalent*** to a uniform distribution on a spherical shell. But that, only for whatever things you do *inside the volume*, *not outside*.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not imply that the surface is spherical and charged uniformly.

Imagine  a charged conducting shell of arbitrary shape.  (An ellipsoid is a simple example.)  Gauss' Law tells us that the charges in the conductor fly to the outside surface of the conductor, and the distribution of charges is such that the E-field inside is zero.  But for a non-spherical conductor, the charge distribution is explicitly *not* spherical, and the charge distribution on it is not uniform.

Comment: I don't understand any of this.

Comment: @garyp who spoke of a charged conductor here? What you want with an ellipsoidal conductor?

Comment: @Sofia I'm simply providing an example of a non-spherical surface that has zero E-field within.   Unless I don't understand the question, this is a direct response to the question in the last sentence of the first paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

The other way of phrasing your question: if I have a surface of uniform charge density, and the field inside is zero everywhere, does it follow that the surface is a sphere?

The answer is "yes". Imagine we have a non spherical surface. We know that it is possible to have zero field inside any *conductor* regardless of shape. But we also know that the charge distribution on a non-spherical conductor is non-uniform. And finally we know that if we have a solution that meets the boundary conditions, that is THE solution.

It follows that a non spherical surface with uniform charge distribution dos not have zero field inside - only a spherical surface does.

Comment: I see. And how do you know that a nonsperical conductor has non uniform charge density. Apologies if its a elementary.

Comment: @RobJeffries yes that was a typo.

Comment: @JoshuaBenabou if the charge on a non-spherical conductor is uniform, then the charges closer to the center of charge will have a different potential than the ones further out, and will experience a repulsive force. Charge will redistribute until the surface is an equipotential. Intuitively the charges like to "get as far from each other as possible".